# Dynamic named range referencing table changing to static ref in chart

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I'm using Excel 365.

I have a table on a sheet called `Clinic`.
I've used a table so that the End Of Week formula (`=row above + 7`) copies down when data is added to a new row.

```
| End Of Week | New Cards Awaiting Process | Internal Priority |
|-------------|----------------------------|-------------------|
| 06/09/2019  |                            |                   |
| 13/09/2019  | 29                         |                   |
| 20/09/2019  | 18                         |                   |
| 27/09/2019  | 17                         |                   |
| 04/10/2019  | 15                         | 22                |
| 11/10/2019  | 13                         |                   |
```

I want to chart this data for the previous six weeks only, so when new data is added the chart references should move down by a row.

I've tried two different formula to reference the correct cells:

- `=INDEX(Clinic!$BB:$BB,COUNTA(Clinic!$BB:$BB)-3):INDEX(Clinic!$BB:$BB,COUNTA(Clinic!$BB:$BB)+2)`
- `=OFFSET(Clinic!$BB$6,COUNTA(Clinic!$BB:$BB)-9,,6)`

Both these formula reference the correct information and are placed in named ranges (I've tried *Workbook* & *Worksheet* scope).

I then use these named ranges in the chart reference:
`=SERIES(Clinic!$BC$5,Clinic!Internal_Dates,Clinic!Internal_Process,1)`
I've tried adding to the formula bar (as above) and adding into the *Select Data Source* dialog box but they convert to static formula.

**The only way I've found to keep the named ranges is not to use a table for the data source, but this stops the formula from copying down.**

Is there a way, without VBA, to keep these named ranges in the chart while keeping the table formatting for the data?

Comment: Thanks for this "The only way I've found to keep the named ranges is not to use a table for the data source".